# org.openntf.domino.Session HTTP JVM: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lotus/domino/NotesCalendar

Tags: xpages

org.openntf.domino API M2.5C on Domino 8.5.3FP2 win 64.

I have imported M2.5C into my project, which currently uses "traditional" Domino java techniques.  I seem to having problems creating a session, getting current database, either directly from the openntf api or using the Factory.fromLotus() method as I get the following error:

HTTP JVM: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lotus/domino/NotesCalendar

e.g.

```
 import org.openntf.domino.*;
 import org.openntf.domino.utils.*;

 org.openntf.domino.Session s = null; 
 lotus.domino.Session sess_dom = DominoAccess.getCurrentSession(); 
 //  All good so far and I can do whatever with this session
 //  object e.g. sess_dom.getEffectiveUserName();

 // All these error
 s = Factory.getSession();
 s = XSPUtil.getCurrentSession();
 s = Factory.fromLotus(sess_dom, org.openntf.domino.Session.class, null);
```

If I follow Factory.getSession(), it looks like it ultimately does a fromLotus().  I must be missing something really simple, any help would be greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nick, the OpenNTF Domino API requires Domino 9.0.  Earlier versions (including 8.5.3) do not have the NotesCalendar class in the IBM-provided API.

A few people have expressed interest in a backwards-compatible version, but we have been hesitant as it would be a true fork. We've been looking for a maintainer for such a fork. Are you interested?

Comment: Hmm, conundrum: do I make upgrading of production servers more of a priority, dev straight to 9 or make backwards compatible.  The processes to get prod'n servers upgraded means a fair bit of red tape and testing, this may not be happen for a couple of months.  Not really sure of time or effort to create backwards compatible version, you may be able to answer. But if makes sense, then yes, I would be interested in maintaining fork.  How shall we communicate?